# How to get file path when uploading a file?

Tags: java, file, csv, servlets, file-upload

I'm having a trouble getting the file path of the folder when the user is trying to upload a csv file. Currently, I've hard-coded the file path so that it only gets the csv file from that directory. I need to get the current file path where the file is located so that when the file is transferred to another folder, the servlet will still be able to read the content of my csv file.

Here's my code:

```
String file = request.getParameter("csvFile");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String fileurl = "/home/user/" + file;
```

I want the `fileurl` to get the current file path where the csv file is located. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `fileUrl` value get returned in the response?

Comment: no. I just need the fileUrl so that it can get the csv file from the home/user/ and read it through bufferedreader

Comment: Just by the name of that file, you can't get the file path as there can be more than one file with that name, residing in different directories, could you provide a bit more info on the use case?